# Concurrency and connection issues to Access DB stored in SharePoint Library

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, sharepoint, ado

**Short version:** (after finding out the answer)

I have an Excel VBA application with an MS Access database (.accdb) on a SharePoint library.
The behavior that was examined (and apparently documented - see answer):

1. It takes a long time to perform the ADODB Open and Close methods (~15 seconds).
2. If multiple users are connected at the same time to the database, only the changes made by the user which closed the database connection **LAST** are saved. Changing cursor types, cursor locations or lock types didn't help. No error shown.

Why does this happen?

**Original Question:**

First question here. Hope this isn't too wordy:

I've built an Excel application using VBA to communicate with an MS Access database (.accdb) that should have support for concurrent users accessing it. It is meant to be placed on a Sharepoint site as an accessible file (not integrated into it in any other way). When I was testing the Excel file and the database on my home network it worked like a charm, transactions and all. However, once I migrated it to Sharepoint, I've noticed some extreme differences from the way it acted on my personal network:

1. The ADODB {.open} and {.close} methods take at least 15 seconds each (making Excel freeze until done). Due to this, I've decided to open and close connections only once throughout the lifetime of the application, and restore the connection if it is broken along the way. I'm aware of the fact that this is highly not recommended, but can't afford having my users wait so long. This hasn't caused any problems that I'm aware of, perhaps apart from the one I'm about to explain.
2. The problem: Changes aren't saved to the actual database unless all active user connections to the database are closed, even if the only active thing is the connection. Everything passes without errors for each user when attempting to update, and each user can access his/her changes, I suppose until all connections are terminated. I tried all possible cursor types and lock types, nothing seemed to work. It is as if a local copy of the database is stored on the user's computer (hence the long wait while opening and closing the connection), and updates are stored on the temporary version, not the actual one.

I tried all possible combinations for cursor types, cursor locations, lock types and what not (found out along the way that dynamic cursors aren't supported in my case - I wonder if that's the answer).

Due to this I have no other choice but to make the program accessible to only one user at a time, or changes seem to get lost along the way, making the program highly unreliable.

I read something about having to "flush the buffer" or "refresh the cursor". Is this even possible/necessary? Or the case? If I'm using a keyset cursor, shouldn't my edited records be shown to all other users? (not talking about new ones)

For what it's worth, I map the path to the sharepoint folder before accessing it.

Have any of you experienced something like this? Or have any suggestions?

If you need samples of my code I'll post it soon. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem:

> Although you can save an Access database file to OneDrive or a SharePoint document library, we recommend that you avoid opening an Access database from these locations. The file may be downloaded locally for editing and then uploaded again once you save your changes to SharePoint. If more than one person opens the Access database from SharePoint, multiple copies of the database may get created and some unexpected behaviors may occur. This recommendation applies to all types of Access files including a single database, a split database, and the .accdb, .accdc, .accde, and .accdr file formats. For more information on deploying Access, see Deploy an Access application.

Source: [Ways to share an Access desktop database](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/ways-to-share-an-access-desktop-database-03822632-da43-4d8f-ba2a-68da245a0446)